# .net core modelstate invalid using selectlist with guid

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-8.0, .net-3.0

So i am in the process of creating my 3rd crud service inside my webapp. the webapp is running .net core 3.0. my 2 previous crud apps where project and employee. so a user/employee does some work on a project.

so for my 'work' crud service/application in my creation view I need to have a dropdown of all projects and a dropdown for all employees and a view inputs. for employee and project the id is a guid because its unique. But i am seem to having an issue that my modelstateis always invalid.

ps: also my data model so to say it doesn't make any foreign keys for example project id with work id or employee id."

model for work:

```
public class Work
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(512, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot exceed 512 characters!")]
        public string Description { get; set; }        

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Working hours")]
        public double WorkingHours { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Employee")]
        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public Employee Employee { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Project")]
        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

        public Projects Project { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime dateAdded { get; set; }


    }
```

viewmodel:

```
public class WorkViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Projects> projects { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Employee> employees { get; set; }
        public Guid employeeId { get; set; }
        public Guid projectId { get; set; }
        public Work work { get; set; }
    }
```

create view:

```
@model TimeSheetTool.ViewModels.WorkViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form asp-action="Save">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select asp-for="projectId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.projects, "Id", "Name"))">
                    <option>Please select one!</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="projectId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="work.Description" class="control-labels"></label>
                <input asp-for="work.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="work.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="work.WorkingHours" class="control-labels"></label>
                <input asp-for="work.WorkingHours" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="work.WorkingHours"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select asp-for="employeeId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.employees, "Id", "Name"))">
                    <option>Please select one!</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="employeeId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong with this? as you can see in the create view for select list I have got Id i assume it would actually need guid since i'm using guid but then the app won't work at all.

Comment: It is because of the `Work` property in the view model. It has validation, which if not satisfied will cause the issue

Comment: @nkosi yup thx, what i did is the viewmodel implements project employee and work, but my work model also implements project and employee which is kinda duplicate, so i removed work from my viewmodel and just added the rpoperties and that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the Work property in the view model.

```
public Work work { get; set; }
```

It has validation, which if not satisfied will cause the invalid model state issue

Add the necessary properties to the view model

```
public class WorkViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<Projects> projects { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Employee> employees { get; set; }
    public Guid employeeId { get; set; }
    public Guid projectId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(512, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot exceed 512 characters!")]
    public string Description { get; set; }        
    [Display(Name = "Working hours")]
    public double WorkingHours { get; set; }
}
```

and populate them as needed when invoking the action to bind the view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-labels"></label>
    <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="WorkingHours" class="control-labels"></label>
    <input asp-for="WorkingHours" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="WorkingHours"></span>
</div>
```

The values can be copied over to the model on post

Comment: jup thx i figured it out yesterday myself since in my work model employeeid and projectid has required attribute. but many thx for the reply